# History, Diff and reverts of persisted objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In a Spring MVC / Spring Data project I need to implement a mechanism to track history, present differences and revert the changes to an entity object.

Let's say I have an entity with relationships with others like this:

```
@Entity
public Class ModelA{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ModelB modelB;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ModelC modelC;
}
```

I want to have the list of changes, the ability to compare and revert them. I know that using Ruby there are libs that provide this kind of functionality, but I'm not aware if such thing exist in Java.

Spring has a [historiography API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/history/package-summary.html) and Hibernate Envers had been incorporated in Core functionality, although I still can't find a simple example or some guidance how to implement it.

If it's relevant the used database is PostgreSQL and Oracle 11g, but I want to keep it database independent.

Comment: I see once implementation of storing data with history support. It was whited without any framework, on PLSQL, and it was horrible. Main idea - you have PK = entity Id + time of revision. All select queries can return last revision (by default) or revision on some time. Drawback of this method - very difficult to write code and queries, slow sql queries and loosing FK ability. I know, it is not answer to your question, but maybe this help you in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, what you ask is some sort of [Memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) to manage some entities subject to history tracking.

In this case, my suggestion is to configure Spring Data to support a second database (i.e. a tracking database), where you will insert the history of the entities you are interested in.
Then you may create a new annotation (possibly using AspectJ) and apply it to your DAOs (e.g. to your repositories, if you are using them). This way, every time you make a CRUD operation on a tracked class (or, more precisely, on a dao/repository that manages a class you want to track), you make an "insert" in the tracking database storing the change that just occurred.

I can give you [this reference](http://sichernmic.blogspot.it/2013/08/memento-pattern-with-aspectj.html), which does not match exactly your need, but may support you at finding the one solution that solves your issue.

Comment: This is clearly the best option at the moment, at least it gives clear guidance. Despite from not give an complete example, I will accept this answer due the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use Enver and [Auditions](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#example) instead please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like more details, I've seen the API's but I was looking for a simple example. Saving the history of an object seems easy to do, but manage revisions, revert and diff's are not.

Comment: The example don't show how to manage revisions, just to save and retrieve.

Comment: You like to save Revisions that has changed in the past? This is not allowed because of strange behaviours to n-m relations! You can read revisions only and merge their state back to the Database. This is a very individual and handy job, there is no (and will never be) a framework for!

Answer (score 1):

One very interesting approach is given by Christian Bauer (Hibernate committer and author of Hibernate in Action and Java Persistence with Hibernate) in [this post](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HistoryTriggersAndHibernate).

You create a HISTORY table:

```
create table ITEM (
    ITEM_ID    NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    DESC       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRICE      NUMBER(19,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ITEM_ID)
)

create table ITEM_HISTORY (
    ITEM_ID    NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    DESC       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRICE      NUMBER(19,2) NOT NULL,
    VERSION    NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ITEM_ID, VERSION)
)
```

Then you map entities to a view instead:

```
create or replace view ITEM_VERSIONED (ITEM_ID, VERSION, DESC, PRICE) as
    select I.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID,
        (select max(IH.VERSION)
            from ITEM_HISTORY HI
            where HI.ITEM_ID = I.ITEM_ID) as VERSION,
        I.DESC as DESC,
        I.PRICE as PRICE
    from   ITEM I
```

and the DML statements are resolved by INSTEAD OF TRIGGERS which are supported by PostgreSQL and Oracle:

```
create or replace trigger ITEM_INSERT
    instead of insert on ITEM_VERSIONED begin
    
    insert into ITEM(ITEM_ID, DESC, PRICE)
           values (:n.ITEM_ID, :n.DESC, :n.PRICE);
           
    insert into ITEM_HISTORY(ITEM_ID, DESC, PRICE, VERSION)
           values (:n.ITEM_ID, :n.DESC, :n.PRICE, :n.VERSION);
end;

create or replace trigger ITEM_UPDATE
    instead of update on ITEM_VERSIONED begin
    
    update ITEM set
            DESC = :n.DESC,
            PRICE = :n.PRICE,
           where
            ITEM_ID = :n.ITEM_ID;
           
    insert into ITEM_HISTORY(ITEM_ID, DESC, PRICE, VERSION)
           values (:n.ITEM_ID, :n.DESC, :n.PRICE, :n.VERSION);
end;
```

This will work even for other applications that may not use Hibernate, yet they operate on the same DB.

Comment: I've seen the mentioned post, I tend to avoid solutions which need database logic.